# Unable to post the message user(own) timeline using Facebook API in v3.0

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, api

**V3.0**

I want to post the content/message using Facebook Graph API in v3.0 but unable to post the message, its through the following error.

```
{
  "error": {
            "message": "(#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission",
            "type": "OAuthException",
            "code": 200,
            "fbtrace_id": "xxx"
          }
}
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
try {
     // Returns a `FacebookFacebookResponse` object
     $response = $fb->post('/xxxxxxxxxxx3x02/feed', 
     array (
        'link' => 'test.com',
        'message' => 'Test'
     ),
    '{access-token}'
    );
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

**Facebook Permission**

In v3.0, the "publish_actions" is removed.

How could we post the message through PHP SDK into user timeline?.Please advise?

Comment: As a sidenote, most of the links in the PHP SDK docs are 404ing. Also, the sdk doesn't seem to be updated yet: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/releases Maybe you can target the older v2 api in the meantime?

Comment: Hi Loek

Thanks for your reply,

When i was try with old version of Facebook API v2.10. It seems to be working properly in old version.

New version V3.0 is not post in my own timeline using API.

Anyone suggest me which permission suppose to need to post the user timeline?

Comment: _“How could we post the message through PHP SDK into user timeline?”_ - you can’t. If Facebook wanted you to still be able to do this, they would not have removed the permission in the first place - duh! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24

Comment: Thanks for your reply.